# Python ML Backward Elimination deleting the wrong arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning

I tried to build the optimal model by using Backward Elimination when I am practicing machine learning course,and I think I've done something wrong in my define code,please help me to find out what is the problem.

The function should run correctly is to delete the P-values that are greater than 0.05.

I've tried my idea on console step by step,and when i tried to transform my idea into define code something went wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

# Automatic Backward Elimination
def backwardelimination(x,sl):
    regressor_OLS=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    for i in range(0,len(x[0])):
        maxp=max(regressor_OLS.pvalues)  #Find the max P-value
        if maxp>sl:               #delete the max P-value which is greater than SL
            x = np.delete(x,maxp,axis=1)  
            regressor_OLS=sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    return x

X=np.append(arr = np.ones((50,1)).astype(int) , values = X ,axis = 1)
X_opt=X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]      
SL=0.05                                  #Significance Level
X_Modeled=backwardelimination(X_opt,SL)
```

This is the [original matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMDxA.jpg), I expect this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtKwX.jpg),but somehow became [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzoHX.jpg).

`X_opt=X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]`   Original matrix

`X_opt=X[:,[0,3]]`          What it should be(after delete the P-values that greater then 0.05)!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the index of `pmax` to the `np.delete()` fun not `pmax` value itself, for that first convert p-values to a list then its really easy.

```
def backwardelimination(x, sl):
    regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
    for i in range(0, len(x[0])):
        c = list(regressor_OLS.pvalues)  # <-- list conversion
        j = c.index(max(c))              # <-- getting the index of max value
        maxp = max(regressor_OLS.pvalues).astype(float)
        if maxp > sl:
            x = np.delete(x, j, axis=1)  # <-- insert j in delete as an index
            regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()
    print(regressor_OLS.summary())
    return x
```